# 10th anniversary of Tor.SE

Tags: discussion

The first day of October in 2013 was a big day. Back then, https://tor.stackexchange.com was launched as a new beta site. This means that we can celebrate our 10th birthday. Hooray!

You can find more than 7000 answers here which help you to understand Tor better and which could strengthen your privacy. Thanks to you all who made this possible!

While we're celebrating let's also take a moment to pause and think about the nice things. How has the site helped you? How do you use Tor now compared to ten or five years ago? What do you like or dislike? Do you have a favourite question or answer on the site? It would be great if you could share some of these details with our community, as an answer on this post!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this community was something I liked from the start and I'm happy to be the part of it! Tor usage and daily necessity grows month by month worldwide as censorship hardens - as far as I can see. My Tor usage didn't changed since all these years: running some nodes and not just for Tor, also helping another people to rise their own ones. It was good and bad times, as usual :) Bad times were when a bot-runned account was just flooding the community with any discussion about the wrong things it said ending like a mid-school low-end talk, also taking a break in moderation during my life events was a must thing to do, because I literally had no time for this duty I love to perform. Good things are much more brighter and frequent, I was able to help people to drop down the illegal surveillance and defeat censorship. It was nice to talk to them here and in PM's and voice, but one person flied to say thanks and have some beer from Washington, DC to Moscow, Russia where I am - and we've had a great time! The thing that we must do - as a community - is to have the Onion address set up for our website :) Or it's a bit odd that Tor-dedicated community does not have an Onion address :D I have already proposed it many times before and even offered my help in setting it up, but here we are. CheerZ!